# C# change color for each line in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, .net

I have a text, that have lines, statring with "#". How can i make all text black, and only these lines green?

Comment: Please search SO befor you ask questions. Most probably someone else had that question already and it was answered mutliple times.

Comment: what did you try? include the parts of your code needed to show and reproduce the scenario, and describe which problems/errors occur.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this as follows:

```
String[] lines = ...

foreach (String line in lines)
{
    box.SelectionStart = box.TextLength;
    box.SelectionLength = 0;

    if (line.StartsWith("#"))
        box.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
    else
        box.SelectionColor = Color.Black;

    box.AppendText(line + Environment.NewLine);
}
```